# Magento2 Programmatically apply cart price rule

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have created a cart price rule in admin, now I want to apply this rule programmatically in my code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to create the rule or you want to apply?

Comment: apply. I created it in admin already

Comment: hi @DhirenVasoya I just wanted to confirm is this possible https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336482/how-to-apply-following-free-shipping-cart-price-rule